# Cyrillics in LINQ to SQL database

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql, csv

I have comma separated file with cyrillics characters. When I read from it using StreamReader the characters are OK. I'm writing the file in LINQ to SQL database, however the column with cyrillics is written with ?????? .The column is nvarchar type. Does somebody had the same problem?

Comment: try to insert cyrillics with an "insert into.." statement. If that does not work, it is the database. Otherwise it is linq-to-sql...

Comment: when I write into database directly without code cyrillics is written

Comment: can you debug linq-2-sql and just before SubmitChanges inspect the classes. Are they good?

Answer (score 0):

i think that is a encoding problem, maybe the SQL DB has not the properly library to encoding the Cyrillics.

take a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-cyrillic-sets.html

Comment: if your broswer has a correct set-up for the Cyrillic encoding, when you see the ??? ? when you retrieve data from the server with a query?

Answer (score 0):

try Encoding.Utf8:

```
new StreamReader("THE PATH", Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: When I try to write the content on the file on webpage the characters are cyrillics, the problem is that in the database column the characters are ?????

Comment: what is your field type in your table in database. It should be nvarchar

Answer (score 0):

You may have to change the collattion of you database

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180175.aspx